# Adding whitespace to an ArrayList element

Tags: java, string, arraylist, whitespace

Given an element of an ArrayList, something like:

```
List<String> bunchOfLetters = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and a standard method to add some letters to it, say

```
public void makeUpSomeLetters(){

bunchOfLetters.add("abcdefg");
```

I understand that to traverse an ArrayList to inspect elements
I need to do

```
for(int i = 0; i<bunchOfLetters.size(); i++)
{
```

but I am clueless how to add whitespace to the end of it, e.g. making the end result become something like:

```
[abcdefg ]
```

as opposed to just

```
[abcdefg]
```

purpose: I would like to add said whitespace so that I may take a substring for said element without having the console omit characters. thank you for your time.
Cheers!

Comment: Can you be more detailed please? What are the elements of your arraylist? Strings, Characters? Can you show some code how to construct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("ABCD");
list.set(0, list.get(0) + " ");
System.out.print(list.get(0).equals("ABCD "));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
true
```

Comment: @ Eng.Fouad that did the trick! My bad re: lack of initial specificity (pre-editing). I've since specified it.